# Patch SUPEE-6788 - Customer register template Hunk FAILED

Tags: magento-1.9, template, ce-1.9.1.0, security, patches

With our Magento version 1.9.1.0 when we are trying to apply patch via SSH it fails with following error

```
Hunk #1 FAILED at 43.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml.rej
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 28.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml.rej
```

What should be the issue? if I am going to replace the files with default Magento installation will it will then cause issues if these were modified earlier?

Comment: Please post the contents of `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml.rej` I'm guessing you've edited that file which caused the patch to fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed all prior security patches?  They are required for the SUPEE-6788 patch to succeed.  http://magereport.com can help determine if previous patches have not been applied.

Otherwise your `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml` file likely has modifications which are preventing the patch.  In that case:

1. Create a backup of your current file
2. restore the stock 1.9 version of the file
3. apply the patch
4. merge your customized file and the patched file